# How to use powershell to obtain the data from excel and select from SQL

Tags: sql, powershell

I have an excel file that contain a list of staff information, 
now I want to use the column `Staff_ID` in **xlsx** to select those `Staff_ID` from **sql** table and get the result by e`xport_CSV`, so I try to write a powershell that could be run in schedule task.

How should I get the information from excel and select those data from sql table?

```
$SQLServer = "ServerName"
    $SQLDBName = "DBName"
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = 
    $SQLDBName; User ID= YourUserID; Password= YourPassword" 
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = 'StoredProcName'
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) 
    $SqlConnection.Close() 
    $gSqlAuthMode = True
    SELECT * FROM [DBName].[dbo].[DETAILS] WHERE [STATUS] not like 'Inactive-%'  ORDER BY NUMBER ASC 


    $List = Import-XLSX -Path "D:\Stafflist.xlsx"

    foreach ($item in $List){
        If ((?? -eq $item.StaffCuid.toUpper().trim())) {
                $Report = [PSCustomObject] @{
            }
        }
    }

$Report | Export-Csv D:\report.csv -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation -append
}
```

Comment: This would be MUCH more efficient, and require much less code using SSIS; have you considered that as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Import-Excel` cmdlet from the famous [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/6.1.0) module and [Invoke-SQLCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) (part of SQL management tools)

```
$Excel = Import-Excel -Path D:\Stafflist.xlsx
Foreach($Row in $Excel) {
 $StaffID = $Row.StaffCuid.toUpper().trim()
 $Query = "create your query here with $StaffId"
 Invoke-SQLCmd -Query $Query -ServerInstance "$ServerName\$DBName"
}
```